# ssh connects to wrong server

Tags: ssh, dns

I changed the ip address of an ubuntu server in DNS

before

```
 10.x.x.111
```

after

```
10.x.x.222
```

I've flushed the dns cache, and yet when I try and ssh into the machine, ssh still tries to connect to the old IP.

```
host foo.example.com
10.10.10.222    <= 222 is the correct *new* ip address



ssh -vv -F /dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  foo.example.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /dev/null
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to foo.example.com [10.x.x.111] port 22.   <= 111 is the incorrect *old* address
```

I've verified that the old IP is not present in `/etc/hosts` `~/.ssh/known_hosts` nor `~/.ssh/config`

Why is ssh finding the wrong ip address?

**Update**

After waiting overnight, it appears that this morning ssh now connects to the correct ip address.

Since there are no answers, I'll expound on the question. How does `ssh` differ from `host` in the way that they resolve dns names?

**Update2**

I've reproduced this again. `host` shows the right ip, `ping` and `ssh` show the old ip.

Here is an strace output of ping
http://pastebin.com/ifnrqDP6

Comment: If you ping `foo.example.com` does it resolve to the correct address or not?

Comment: It will take a while to be flushed in all dns servers, so you might wait a little

Comment: How are you flushing the DNS cache?

Comment: Is there more than one A record with the same name?

Comment: This is on a Mac, which ships with an old openssh. I've verified that there is only 1 A record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that on OSX, there are multiple caches that need to be flushed. Since my workstation is a Mac, running yosemite, I ran the following

```
sudo discoveryutil mdnsflushcache
```

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202516

It turns out that I also needed to flush the udns cache

```
 sudo discoveryutil udnsflushcaches
```

Comment: Excellent!  `ssh -v my.host.name` was showing that ssh and nslookup did not agree on what the IP address for my.host.name was. Thought it was something I'd done on my.host.name; turns out it is a local Yosemite problem that this fixed.

Comment: In 10.10.4 apple likely will revert back to using mDNSResponder from discoveryD which should fix this issue http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/01/why-dns-in-os-x-10-10-is-broken-and-what-you-can-do-to-fix-it/ http://www.macrumors.com/2015/05/26/apple-discoveryd-replaced-with-mdnsresponder/

Comment: I had this bug on debian 8 (jessie), so it is not osx-specific. For me, only ssh tried to connect to the old IP address (ping and wget worked fine). I did not find a solution but the problem only persisted for about an hour, so I used the IP address directly until then.